# Как остановить event on_message discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

У меня есть команда с вложенной функцией `on_message`. Как мне остановить его при выполнеии определённого условия?

Пример:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('started')

    @bot.event
    async def on_message(mes):
        if mes.author.bot:
            return
        msg = mes.content

        if msg != 'break':
            await ctx.send('do something')

        else:
            await ctx.send('stoped')
            await bot.process_commands(mes)
            return
```

При вводе `break` бот пишет `stoped`, но не перестаёт говорить `do something` на каждое сообщение

Comment: Нашёл плохое решение. В `else` можно положить бесконечный цикл `while True: pass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы верно подметили, что цикл `while True: pass` в данном случае не лучшее решение. Ведь после "остановки" функции через написание "*break*", она не больше не будет реагировать, но по прежнему будет работать и использовать системные ресурсы.

Событие `on_message()` лучше создавать отдельно от других функций и использовать глобально, для получения всех сообщений бота.

В общем, в данном случае вам лучше отказаться от функции `on_message()` внутри команды бота `test()`.

---

Из документации узнаем о методе [`wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for), который уже будем использовать внутри отдельной команды.

В данном коде в цикле мы постоянно ждем сообщения, и в случае написания "*break*", `return` прервет выполнение функции, полноценно завершив ее.

```
import asyncio

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('started')

    def check(msg):
        if msg.author.bot:
            return
        else:
            return msg

    while True:
        message = await bot.wait_for('message', check = check)
        if message.content == 'break':
            await ctx.send('stoped')
            return
        else:
            await ctx.send('do something')
```